# spark scala most efficient way to do partial string count

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark, match

I have a question about the most efficient way to do a partial string match in a spark RDD (or scala Array) of 10 million length. Consider the following:

```
val set1 = Array("star wars", "ipad") //These are the String I am looking for
val set2 = RDD[("user1", "star wars 7 is coming out"),
           ("user1", "where to watch star wars"),
           ("user2", "star wars"),
           ("user2", "cheap ipad")]
```

I want to be able to count the number of occurrences of each string that belongs in Set1 that also occurs in Set2. So the result should be something like:

```
Result = ("star wars", 3),("ipad", 1)
```

I also want to count the number of users (i.e. distinct users) who have searched for the term, so the result should be:

```
Result = ("star wars", 2), ("ipad", 1)
```

I had a try at 2 methods, the first involves converting the RDD string to set, flatMapValues and then doing a join operation, but it is memory consuming. The other method I was considering is a regex approach, as only the count is needed and the exact string is given, but I don't know how to make it efficient (by making a function and calling it when I map the RDD?)

I seem to be able to do this quite easily in pgsql using LIKE, but not sure if there is a RDD join that works the same way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use regular expressions in rdd transformations seems feasible.

Comment: it does, but I do have to do it for all 10 million lines of string, so I think it would best if it is a parallel process, or at least distributed evenly to each cluster.

Comment: @qmeeeeeee What is expected size of `Set1` ?

Comment: @Odomontois It is 10, and always 10

Comment: @qmeeeeeee, rdd transformation are automatically parallel processing

Comment: @Yijie Shen would you mind sharing how did you write the regular expression for Set1? Did you do it individually for each one (i.e. generate 10 regex)

Comment: You seem to fit this use case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm#Algorithms_using_a_finite_set_of_patterns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So as advised by Yijie Shen you could use regular expressions:

```
val regex = set1.mkString("(", "|", ")").r
val results = rdd.flatMap {
  case (user, str) => regex.findAllIn(str).map(user -> _)
}
val count = results.map(_._2).countByValue()
val byUser = results.distinct().map(_._2).countByValue()
```

Comment: Oh ok, I see! This makes more sense